# GameObject getting stuck on wall

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a simple character controller. Whenever I continuously walk into a wall, gravity just stops working. For example, if there is a wall in front of me, and I jump and walk into it while in the air, I get stuck vertically. Here is a minimal example of my code:

```cs
[SerializeField] float speed; // player speed
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); // set rigidbody
}
void FixedUpdate() {
    float zInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    float xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    Vector3 targetVel = new(
        xInput == 0 ? 0 : xInput, 0, zInput == 0 ? 0 : zInput); // set new velocity
    targetVel = transform.TransformDirection(targetVel);
    targetVel.Normalize();

    targetVel *= speed; // go fast
    targetVel.y = rb.velocity.y; // keep existing y velocity

    rb.velocity = targetVel;
}
```

Also, I DO want the player to be able to move in midair.

Comment: How have you configured friction on the physics materials for the player object and wall objects, respectively? Usually zeroing out friction on vertical surfaces is enough to allow free sliding.

Comment: The conditions in targetVel can be removed, xInput and zInput placed direcly. Your condition basically says, if it is 0, place a zero there else just place the value. But if the value is zero already, it makes no difference if you use 0 or the value from your input (which is 0)

Comment: Thanks, adding a zero friction physic material to the player and wall worked!

Comment: @DMGregory I think that would make an upvote-worthy answer. [Sorry, couldn't resist... Joking aside, would you rather a nudge or that someone expand into an answer on your behalf?]

Comment: In situations like this, I usually invite the user to answer their own question, because they have a working project handy and can screenshot the settings that worked for them, whereas I'd have to set up a test project first to verify any advice I'm giving. But I'd say it's first come first served, in terms of whoever wants to answer the question. I did a quick search for possible duplicates since I'm sure we've given the zero friction advice before, but I didn't find an obvious match in the 3D case.